# django-rest-framework ManyToManyField create and update

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, manytomanyfield

I'm new in Django, so I have a some problems. I'm using django-rest-framework.
These are my model classes:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    sizes = models.ManyToManyField(Size)
    ...
class Size(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...
```

I would like a product serializer and a viewset that allows to create a product with its sizes.

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sizes = SizeSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'price', 'sizes')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

The serializer written above allows to get the product with its sizes but I can't create or update the sizes of a product.

How can I attain my goal?

Comment: you need to override `create` in your serializer, as far as I know. https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L639

Comment: Ok. With a OneToOneField it's very simple, but with a ManyToManyField no because there isn't the cross table. Am I forced to create it manually and not to use ManyToManyField?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved creating a serializer to get the product with nested sizes, and a serializer to create and update products using only ids.

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sizes = SizeSerializer(many=True) # nested objects

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'price', 'sizes')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)


class ProductCreateUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # no nested objects, it accepts only size ids
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'price', 'sizes')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

Maybe there will be some changes client-side.

Comment: I got an error for update http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40261910/django-rest-many-to-many-model-update-error